# How to prove that for given two arbitrary real numbers $a,b$ such that $b > a$, there exists an integer $n$ such that $na > b$?

Tags: real-analysis

Every proof I have seen uses defines this problem such that $a,b$ are positive real numbers. Any way to prove what I have stated above without defining $ a,b$ such that they are positive real numbers?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: But the OP required only that $n$ be an integer.

Comment: We must require $a \neq 0$.

Comment: It's just too many case testings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably known that when $a$ and $b$ are both positive, this is called Archimedean property of real numbers:

> For any *positive* real numbers $a<b$, there exists a (positive) integer $n$ such that $na>b$.

There are equivalent versions of the statement. For instance,

- For any real number $r>0$, there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $n>r$.
- For any real number $r>0$, there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n}<r$. (This is what Brian means by "there are no positive infinitesimals" in his comment.)

This indeed follows from the completeness of real numbers as follows. Assume by contradiction that no such integer exists and then consider the set $S = \{na:n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\}$. By the assumption, $b$ is an upper bound for $S$; thus by completeness (see the remark below), the set $S$ has a least upper bound $p:=\sup S\in\mathbb{R}$. By the definition of least upper bound, there exists a positive integer $m$ such that
$$
p-a< ma\;.
$$
Consequently, $p< (m+1)a\in S$, which is impossible.

---

In your general statement (where you should assume that $a\ne 0$), you only need to consider two cases if you want to apply directly the completeness of real numbers:

- $0<a<b$;
- $a<0$ and $a<b$.

The first case has been done above. For the second case, consider the set
$
A = \{na:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}\;. 
$
Again, for the sake of argument, assume that $b$ is an upper bound of $A$. By completeness, let $\alpha := \sup A$. Since $a<0$, $\alpha+a<\alpha$; thus there exists an integer $m$ with 
$$
\alpha + a<ma. 
$$
But again this leads to the contradiction that $\alpha<(m-1)a\in A$.

---

**Note.** There are several equivalent statements of the completeness of real numbers. The one above refers to the [least-upper-bound property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property#:~:text=More%20generally%2C%20a%20partially%20ordered,referred%20to%20as%20Dedekind%20completeness.).

**Remark.**

1. In the first case ($0<a<b$) of your general statement, you could define $S=\{na:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ since you only need an integer in the conclusion.
2. The difference between the two cases ($a>0$ vs. $a<0$) only affect the following in the argument:

   - when $a>0$, $\alpha -a<\alpha$;
   - when $a<0$, $\alpha +a<\alpha$.

Answer (score 2):

If you meant that $n$ should be a positive integer, the result is false whenever $a<0<b$, since $na$ is then always negative. If you allow negative integers, however, it’s trivial to prove an extended result once you’ve proved the usual result for positive $a$ and $b$.

If $a<b\le 0$, then $(-1)a>b$. If $a<0\le b$, and $|a|>b$, then $(-1)a>b$. If $a<0<b$ and $|a|\le b$, there is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $n|a|>b$, and clearly $(-n)a>b$. And if $a=0$, the result is false. Thus, whenever $0\ne a<b$ there is an integer $n$ such that $na>b$.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing a solution so quickly. Can the completeness theorem be used do prove this? I was trying to prove this via a contradiction. (Let $b$ be an upper bound of the set $na$ )

Comment: @ShaneK: You’re welcome. It might be possible, but I’m pretty sure that it would involve a fairly ugly division into cases. It’s much easier first to use completeness to prove that there are no positive infinitesimals, from which the result for positive $a$ and $b$ follows immediately, and then to extend **that** by cases.

Comment: +1. I would do the problem in this way too; this is a very natural deduction. If we use the completeness directly, I was thinking it may go ugly for cases as well. But it turns out that we only need to consider two cases. Could you take a look at my answer?

Comment: @sophia: Looks fine to me; +1.